# Mounting multiple instances of the same engine in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm wanting to make use of the new modularity prospects offered by the architecture changes in  rails 3. However, rather than just mount an engine as in the majority of examples...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match "/blog" => Rack::Blog
end
```

...I'd like to mount multiple versions of the same engines, and have those instances independently configured. Something along the lines of...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  match "/news" => Blog.new("path/to/blog_1/config")
  match "/blog" => Blog.new("path/to/blog_2/config")
end
```

Is this sort of functionality catered for? Has anyone implemented anything similar?

Thanks,
fturtle

Comment: hello, i find myself in the same situation, has Rails 4 implemented something that makes this possible?

Answer (score 1):

My gut tells me no, because the namespacing of the first implementation would step on the toes of the second. Though since the files would be the same I guess that wouldn't matter? How did you get on in the end?

Comment: Think we ended up doing something like the devise gem - creating an object/method that's available to the router, and that can dynamically write the routes based on some input.

Comment: @fturtle, how do you implement it? We are having the same situation of mounting the same engine multiple times. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this file: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb That's the method `devise_for` that's being called in the routes file.