# Multiple instances of same rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Why are rails engines designed like singletons?
Is there any way to mount same engine multiple times, using for example different databases for each mounted app?

Here: [Mounting multiple instances of the same engine in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312892/mounting-multiple-instances-of-the-same-engine-in-rails-3)
Is an answer about namespaces, but i think i can re-define view paths by configuration..
So - is there any way to cleanly implement multiple-instance mounting?